# If the LTS expires for Ubuntu 18.04 in april 2021, will the devs of third party apps immediately stop with releasing updates for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: updates, firefox, system, lts

I ask this because i dont know everything about Ubuntu, and how the repos work. I assume the System updates of Ubuntu itself will be halted at that point, but what about other apps, programs ,libraries. Will everything available on that version of Ubuntu (18.04 LTS) concerning updates stop at once, or will it graduately come to a halt ?

Comment: You should already be planning an upgrade for when 20.04**.1** is released ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the fridge notice of Ubuntu 18.04.4's release

> Maintenance updates will be provided for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop,
>   Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud, and Ubuntu Base. All the remaining
>   flavours will be supported for 3 years.

http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/02/12/ubuntu-18-04-4-lts-released/

Flavors only provide 3 years of support so their support only ends in April 2021 for 18.04 LTS (Ubuntu Studio excepted as it was **not** a LTS release).  The main Ubuntu has 5 years of support which can be extended through ESM if you need longer life (https://ubuntu.com/esm)

For Ubuntu Studio 18.04 (https://ubuntustudio.org/2018/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-released/) it was a standard release (not a LTS or *long-term-support* release), however it's support can be extended to 3 years matching other flavors via the use of PPA (https://ubuntustudio.org/2019/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-extended-support/)

*The best place to check is always release notes for the flavor & release you're interested in.*

For repositories best to look up https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu (*noting the 5 years applies to 'main' software, and community based has the same support as the flavors do*)

Comment: FYI:   I provided the text from 18.04.4 notice (via fridge), Ubuntu Studio having already reached EOL officially didn't have provide a 18.04.4 LTS release thus the "all" in Łukasz ‘sil2100’ Zemczak notice was accurate.

Answer (score 4):

Support for 18.04 ends in April 2023, not 2021.

What third parties does at that point is up to said third party. No-one can dictate their behavior. Commercial vendors may continue to support their product on 18.04, or they may ask you to move to a newer distribution.

System updates will be halted, but you can [purchase an extended security maintenance](https://ubuntu.com/esm) for your systems, and continue receiving updates for some years.

Comment: No one can even request that third parties to provide support the full 5 years LTS liftime.or updates at all.